# Function not return the Value in main sub Macro

Tags: vba, excel

Please Find my Below Macro code. I am trying to get return the value in **mm** by function **get_dat** but I am not getting the same. (Date is available in Cells(3, 10)). Please guide on the same.

```
Function get_dat(dates As String) As Date

dates = Month(dates)
If Len(dates) >= 1 Then
dates = 0 & dates
Else: dates = dates
End If
End Function

Sub x()
Dim mm As Integer
mm = get_dat(Cells(3, 10))
End Sub
```

Correction Code:-

```
Function get_dat(dates As String) As String

dates = Month(dates)
If Len(dates) >= 1 Then
dates = 0 & dates
Else: dates = dates
End If
get_dat = dates
End Function

Sub x()
Dim mm As String
mm = get_dat(Cells(3, 10))

End Sub
```

Comment: your `Function get_dat(dates As String) As Date` reutrns a `Date` , not `Integer`, as `mm` is defined. If you want to get the result in mm, then you need your `Function` to be `Function get_dat(dates As String) As Integer`

Comment: I suspect what you are trying to do is `mm = Month(CDate(Cells(3, 10)))` or perhaps (if `mm` was a string) `mm = Format(CDate(Cells(3, 10)),"mm")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be missing a crucial line in `get_dat`.  The final line should be

```
get_dat = dates
```

As mentioned by @ShaiRado in the comments, the declared types don't quite match.  You might want to consider declaring `get_dat as Integer` instead of `as Date`

Comment: Thanks I Have updated my The answer above in my question.